# How call a model validation in different controller?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have two different tables 'users' and 'users_details'. And made two different models 'User' and 'UserDetail'.In user_details table i have user_id and image fields.But I want to validate image field from users controller using cakephp rule.So please give me any idea to do this task as soon as possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if UserDetail is your model into the controller:

```
$this->loadModel('UserDetail');
if ($this->UserDetail->validates()) {
    // it validated logic
} else {
    // didn't validate logic
    $errors = $this->UserDetail->validationErrors;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because UserDetail has "user_id", therefore it should be setup to belongTo User, and User should either hasMany or hasOne UserDetail. You can find out how to set up relationships in the manual http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Then in your Users controller you can access the UserDetail model like such

```
$this->User->UserDetail->set($this->request->data);
if($this->User->UserDetail->validates()) {
    // ...
}
```

Saving Related Model Data: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-hasone-hasmany-belongsto

Validation Data From Controller: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html